# Problems in integrating JQuery Image Uploader with CI

Tags: php, jquery, image, codeigniter, upload

On FF console, I am getting on console and on UI, however the image is successfully uploading on server but JSON shows error "**Empty file upload result**" and in console I am getting the following error.

**Error**

```
TypeError: $(...).live is not a function
    $('#fileupload .files a:not([target^=_blank])').live('click', function (e) {
```

Structure of code is:

**Includes**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>media/image_uploader/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Generic page styles -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>media/image_uploader/css/style.css">
<!-- Bootstrap styles for responsive website layout, supporting different screen sizes -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>media/image_uploader/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css">
<!-- Bootstrap CSS fixes for IE6 -->
<!--[if lt IE 7]><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-ie6.min.css"><![endif]-->
<!-- Bootstrap Image Gallery styles -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>media/image_uploader/css/bootstrap-image-gallery.min.css">
<!-- CSS to style the file input field as button and adjust the Bootstrap progress bars -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>media/image_uploader/css/jquery.fileupload-ui.css">
<!-- CSS adjustments for browsers with JavaScript disabled -->
<noscript>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>media/image_uploader/css/jquery.fileupload-ui-noscript.css">
</noscript>
<!-- Shim to make HTML5 elements usable in older Internet Explorer versions -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="js/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script> 

<script src="<?php echo site_url(); ?>media/image_uploader/js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script> 

<script src="<?php echo site_url(); ?>media/image_uploader/js/tmpl.min.js"></script> 
<!-- The Load Image plugin is included for the preview images and image resizing functionality --> 
<script src="<?php echo site_url(); ?>media/image_uploader/js/load-image.min.js"></script> 
<!-- The Canvas to Blob plugin is included for image resizing functionality --> 
<script src="<?php echo site_url(); ?>media/image_uploader/js/canvas-to-blob.min.js"></script> 
<!-- Bootstrap JS and Bootstrap Image Gallery are not required, but included for the demo --> 
<script src="<?php echo site_url(); ?>media/image_uploader/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
<script src="<?php echo site_url(); ?>media/image_uploader/js/bootstrap-image-gallery.min.js"></script> 
<!-- The Iframe Transport is required for browsers without support for XHR file uploads --> 
<script src="<?php echo site_url(); ?>media/image_uploader/js/jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script> 
<!-- The basic File Upload plugin --> 
<script src="<?php echo site_url(); ?>media/image_uploader/js/jquery.fileupload.js"></script> 
<!-- The File Upload file processing plugin --> 
<script src="<?php echo site_url(); ?>media/image_uploader/js/jquery.fileupload-fp.js"></script> 
<!-- The File Upload user interface plugin --> 
<script src="<?php echo site_url(); ?>media/image_uploader/js/jquery.fileupload-ui.js"></script>
```

**Main.js**

```
$(function () {
    'use strict';

    // Initialize the jQuery File Upload widget:
    $('#fileupload').fileupload();

    // Enable iframe cross-domain access via redirect option:
    $('#fileupload').fileupload(
        'option',
        'redirect',
        window.location.href.replace(
            /\/[^\/]*$/,
            '<?php echo site_url(); ?>media/image_uploader/js/cors/result.html?%s'
            )
        );

    $('#download-files > .template-download > .add').each(function(e){
        alert(e);
    });

    // Load existing files:
    $('#fileupload').each(function () {
        var that = this;
        $.getJSON(this.action, function (result) {
            if (result && result.length) {
                $(that).fileupload('option', 'done')
                .call(that, null, {
                    result: result
                });
            }
        });
    });


    // Open download dialogs via iframes,
    // to prevent aborting current uploads:
    $('#fileupload .files a:not([target^=_blank])').live('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('<iframe style="display:none;"></iframe>')
        .prop('src', this.href)
        .appendTo('body');
    });

});
```

**Upload Handler**

```
  function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));

//Set relative Path with CI Constant
        $this->setPath_img_upload_folder("assets/img/articles/");
        $this->setPath_img_thumb_upload_folder("assets/img/articles/thumbnails/");


//Delete img url
        $this->setDelete_img_url(base_url() . 'admin/deleteImage/');


//Set url img with Base_url()
        $this->setPath_url_img_upload_folder(base_url() . "assets/img/articles/");
        $this->setPath_url_img_thumb_upload_folder(base_url() . "assets/img/articles/thumbnails/");
  }


    public function index() {
      $this->load->view('upload_view');
   }



    public function upload_img() {
        $name = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
        $name = strtr($name, 'ÀÁÂÃÄÅÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÒÓÔÕÖÙÚÛÜÝàáâãäåçèéêëìíîïðòóôõöùúûüýÿ', 'AAAAAACEEEEIIIIOOOOOUUUUYaaaaaaceeeeiiiioooooouuuuyy');

// remplacer les caracteres autres que lettres, chiffres et point par _

         $name = preg_replace('/([^.a-z0-9]+)/i', '_', $name);

        //Your upload directory, see CI user guide
        $config['upload_path'] = $this->getPath_img_upload_folder();

        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|JPG|GIF|PNG';
        $config['max_size'] = '1000';
        $config['file_name'] = $name;

       //Load the upload library
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

       if ($this->do_upload()) {

            //If you want to resize 
            $config['new_image'] = $this->getPath_img_thumb_upload_folder();
            $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
            $config['source_image'] = $this->getPath_img_upload_folder() . $name;
            $config['create_thumb'] = FALSE;
            $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
            $config['width'] = 193;
            $config['height'] = 94;

            $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);

            $this->image_lib->resize();

           $data = $this->upload->data();

            //Get info 
            $info = new stdClass();

            $info->name = $name;
            $info->size = $data['file_size'];
            $info->type = $data['file_type'];
            $info->url = $this->getPath_img_upload_folder() . $name;
            $info->thumbnail_url = $this->getPath_img_thumb_upload_folder() . $name; //I set this to original file since I did not create thumbs.  change to thumbnail directory if you do = $upload_path_url .'/thumbs' .$name
            $info->delete_url = $this->getDelete_img_url() . $name;
            $info->delete_type = 'DELETE';


           //Return JSON data
           if (IS_AJAX) {   //this is why we put this in the constants to pass only json data
                echo json_encode(array($info));
                //this has to be the only the only data returned or you will get an error.
                //if you don't give this a json array it will give you a Empty file upload result error
                //it you set this without the if(IS_AJAX)...else... you get ERROR:TRUE (my experience anyway)
            } else {   // so that this will still work if javascript is not enabled
                $file_data['upload_data'] = $this->upload->data();
                echo json_encode(array($info));
            }
        } else {

           // the display_errors() function wraps error messages in <p> by default and these html chars don't parse in
           // default view on the forum so either set them to blank, or decide how you want them to display.  null is passed.
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors('',''));

            echo json_encode(array($error));
        }


       }
 // }


//Function for the upload : return true/false
  public function do_upload() {

        if (!$this->upload->do_upload()) {

            return false;
        } else {
            //$data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

            return true;
        }
     }

public function deleteImage() {

        //Get the name in the url
        $file = $this->uri->segment(3);

        $success = unlink($this->getPath_img_upload_folder() . $file);
        $success_th = unlink($this->getPath_img_thumb_upload_folder() . $file);

        //info to see if it is doing what it is supposed to 
        $info = new stdClass();
        $info->sucess = $success;
        $info->path = $this->getPath_url_img_upload_folder() . $file;
        $info->file = is_file($this->getPath_img_upload_folder() . $file);
        if (IS_AJAX) {//I don't think it matters if this is set but good for error checking in the console/firebug
            echo json_encode(array($info));
        } else {     //here you will need to decide what you want to show for a successful delete
            var_dump($file);
        }
    }

    public function get_files() {

        $this->get_scan_files();
    }

    public function get_scan_files() {

        $file_name = isset($_REQUEST['file']) ?
                basename(stripslashes($_REQUEST['file'])) : null;
        if ($file_name) {
            $info = $this->get_file_object($file_name);
        } else {
            $info = $this->get_file_objects();
        }
        header('Content-type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($info);
    }

    protected function get_file_object($file_name) {
        $file_path = $this->getPath_img_upload_folder() . $file_name;
        if (is_file($file_path) && $file_name[0] !== '.') {

            $file = new stdClass();
            $file->name = $file_name;
            $file->size = filesize($file_path);
            $file->url = $this->getPath_url_img_upload_folder() . rawurlencode($file->name);
            $file->thumbnail_url = $this->getPath_url_img_thumb_upload_folder() . rawurlencode($file->name);
            //File name in the url to delete 
            $file->delete_url = $this->getDelete_img_url() . rawurlencode($file->name);
            $file->delete_type = 'DELETE';

            return $file;
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected function get_file_objects() {
        return array_values(array_filter(array_map(
             array($this, 'get_file_object'), scandir($this->getPath_img_upload_folder())
                   )));
    }


    public function getPath_img_upload_folder() {
        return $this->path_img_upload_folder;
    }

    public function setPath_img_upload_folder($path_img_upload_folder) {
        $this->path_img_upload_folder = $path_img_upload_folder;
    }

    public function getPath_img_thumb_upload_folder() {
        return $this->path_img_thumb_upload_folder;
    }

    public function setPath_img_thumb_upload_folder($path_img_thumb_upload_folder) {
        $this->path_img_thumb_upload_folder = $path_img_thumb_upload_folder;
    }

    public function getPath_url_img_upload_folder() {
        return $this->path_url_img_upload_folder;
    }

    public function setPath_url_img_upload_folder($path_url_img_upload_folder) {
        $this->path_url_img_upload_folder = $path_url_img_upload_folder;
    }

    public function getPath_url_img_thumb_upload_folder() {
        return $this->path_url_img_thumb_upload_folder;
    }

    public function setPath_url_img_thumb_upload_folder($path_url_img_thumb_upload_folder) {
        $this->path_url_img_thumb_upload_folder = $path_url_img_thumb_upload_folder;
    }

    public function getDelete_img_url() {
        return $this->delete_img_url;
    }

    public function setDelete_img_url($delete_img_url) {
        $this->delete_img_url = $delete_img_url;
    }
```

Any help will be highly appreciable.
Thank you.

Comment: If you are using jQuery 1.9+, jQuery object doesn't have `live` method.

Comment: Yes, I am using 1.9, so what should I do ?

Answer (score 1):

As of jQuery 1.9 jQuery object doesn't have `live` method, you can use `on` method instead:

```
$('#fileupload').on('click', '.files a:not([target^=_blank])', function (e) {
//   ^                                |
//   |                                 ----- target element
//    ----- A static parent or document object
```

Comment: When I try to upload file(s) on server but I am getting this "Empty file upload result"

Comment: @mohsin.mr I have used JQuery file upload plugin, this is the response that you get when file is uploaded, so what is the problem?

Comment: Make sure that you have created folders that have been defined in your controller.

Comment: files are physically uploading on server but still I am receiving this error. You can check the error on [link](http://mohsinrasheed.com/dev/ephrem/10002/0.01/upload/)